# App-In purchase error -1001

Tags: ios4

II've been working on adding in-app purchases and was able to create and test in-app purchases using Store Kit.

Now I am unable to successfully complete any transactions and instead am getting only transactions with transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed.

The transaction.error.code is -1001 and the transaction.error.localizedDescription is "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"!

I have tried removing all products from iTunesConnect, and rebuilt them using different identifiers but that did not help. I have also tried using the App Store app to really connect to the real App Store and download some apps so I do have connectivity. Finally, I have visited the Settings:Store app to make sure I am signed out of my normal app store account.

Answer (score 0):

you probably solved it by now but for others,
sometimes it takes time for apple to process new in app purchases. this is what the message -1001 actually saying

so, cross your fingers and wait for 24-48hours, dont change anything and you will probably be fine,
it will automatically start to work when they finish processing what is needed.